# How to get the value of built, encoded ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I need to grab the `base64-encoded` representation of the `ViewState`. Obviously, this would not be available until fairly late in the request lifecycle, which is OK.

For example, if the output of the page includes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" 
  id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJODU0Njc5MD...==" />
```

I need a way on the server-side to get the value `"/wEPDwUJODU0Njc5MD...=="`

To clarify, I need this value when the page is being rendered, not on PostBack. e.g. I need to know the ViewState value that is being *sent* to the client, not the ViewState I'm getting back from them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rex, I suspect a good place to start looking is solutions that **compress the ViewState** -- they're grabbing ViewState on the server before it's sent down to the client and gzipping it. That's exactly where you want to be.

- [Scott Hanselman on ViewState Compression](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView,guid,febce059-7e7c-439e-af3d-c53d250b3e9c.aspx) (2005)
- [ViewState Compression with System.IO.Compression](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/How-To-Compress-ViewState-in-ASPNET-20-ViewState-Compression-with-SystemIOCompression.aspx) (2007)

Answer (score 4):

See this [blog post](http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/07/09/reducing-the-page-size-by-storing-viewstate-on-server/) where the author describes a method for overriding the default behavior for generating the ViewState and instead shows how to save it on the server Session object.

> In ASP.NET 2.0, ViewState is saved by
>   a descendant of PageStatePersister
>   class. This class is an abstract class
>   for saving and loading ViewsState and
>   there are two implemented descendants
>   of this class in .Net Framework, named
>   HiddenFieldPageStatePersister and
>   SessionPageStatePersister. By default
>   HiddenFieldPageStatePersister is used
>   to save/load ViewState information,
>   but we can easily get the
>   SessionPageStatePersister to work and
>   save ViewState in Session object.

Although I did not test his code, it seems to show exactly what you want: a way to gain access to ViewState code while still on the server, before postback.

Answer (score 2):

I enabled compression following similar articles to those posted above. The key to accessing the ViewState before the application sends it was overriding this method;

```
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
```

You can call the base method within this override and then add whatever additional logic you require to handle the ViewState.