# asp.net mvc 4 routing hide 'details' action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to do url rewriting to only hide our detail action.

- our current url is:   **/subject/details/9839/MONTAGUT-FRENCH-ROMANTICS**
- we want to change it to : **/subject/9839/MONTAGUT-FRENCH-ROMANTICS**
- but we still have other actions in this controller we want all the others' action to keep showing in the url like
  **/subject/category/1/RESTAURANTS**
- is there anyway to make it work?

our mapRoute is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubejctDetails",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = "" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "website.Controllers" }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubjectDetails",
            url: "{controller}/{id}/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = "" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "website.Controllers" }
        );
```

It should accomplish what you want (place it above "Default" route).

My fear is that the route engine will never be able to tell when you want a more classic `/controller/action` route.

To avoid confusing routes, consider a different paradigm: either use a fixed name controller or a leading slug. Then any route that doesn't include the leading slug will be ignored:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubjectDetails",
            url: "subject/{id}/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "subject", action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = "" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "website.Controllers" }
        );
```

Now the route will only apply to url's that start with "subject/"

Comment: thanks for your help but we have other actions in the subject controller we want those action shown in the url as usual

Comment: @leo, are all your relevant actions in your subject controller?

Comment: yes we have other controls like category, list,index... in that controller

Comment: we want the our url looks like stackourflow's. most of our controllers contain a 'detail' action we are planing hide all of them

Comment: @leo, you seem to want incompatible things. If you want a SO-like behavior without specifying a particular slug as they did (questions) AND to have flexibility to use all other routes, it's too much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227348/how-to-get-a-nice-url-like-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-1074-asp-mvc

Comment: @leo, EXACTLY what I said. Their route is using the **Questions** slug. Is that not clear to you?

Comment: how do u think about above question. can i try to wirte some regular expressions for parameters？ so that if we keep the action in the route the default action may be hide

Comment: @leo, seems like you are trying to stretch beyond what the route engine can do. The kind of flexibility you want is not available with any standard engine yet. The best you can do is use a subject slug like in my example and hold the route to THOSE methods. Otherwise you cannot distinguish your route from others.